# Salvar Características no BD

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou começando a trabalhar com PHP, MYSQL agora e me surgiu uma dúvida.

Estou desenvolvendo um site de classificados, o mesmo terá categorias de veículos, imóveis, eletrônicos, etc...

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, o cara seleciona carro por exemplo, carro tem inúmeras características, assim como um celular, um apartamento, etc..como eu posso gravar essas características no BD?

Criar uma tabela pra cada tipo? (carro, caminhão, apartamento, celular...) não né?

Alguém pode me dar um rumo?

Lembrando que todas as características são selecionadas em um checkbox conforme disponibilidade e tipo de anuncio.

Segue div com checkbox

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Características</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Air-Bar </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Ar-Condicionado </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Vidros Elétricos </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Flash </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Câmera Frontal </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> GPS </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Tecnologia NFC </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Detecção Facial </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Dual Chip </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Biometria </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> HDR </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Extensão para Cartão de Memória </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: As características são via input ou ele escolhe conforme disponibilidade e tipo de anuncio?

Comment: Escolhe via checkbox conforme disponibilidade e tipo de anuncio

Comment: Se você tem uma lista de características definidas e o usuário escolhe as opções, você só precisa gravar os ID's. Isso não resolveria o seu caso?

Comment: Mas o checkbox é colocado manualmente no codigo

Comment: Olha podem existir diversas formas de fazer o que você deseja na minha opinião. Salvar uma única string separada por vírgulas das características, uma tabela intermediaria ex: caracteristicas_anuncio (id_anuncio, id_caracteristica, ou id_anuncio, nome_caracteristica) <- em caso de salvar ums tring você pode fazer uma chave composta unique para os dois campos para ele não se repetir.. em fim.... E mais uma coisa, um classificado pode conter mais de uma categoria? Caso sim... a lógica mudaria um pouco também.

Answer (score 0):

ola, como os outros utilizadores disseram, podes fazer de varias formas, na minha opinião, eu guardava numa string, mas em forma de codigo,0 e 1, exemplo: 101 ->Air-Bar:sim,  Ar-Condicionado:não, Vidros Elétricos:sim, etc, mas como eles disseram podes fazer de muitas formas! boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

Amigo o que você vai ter ai é um relacionamento de muitos pra muitos, ou seja, N pra N.

O que você deve fazer é: criar uma tabela chamada "veiculo", outra chamada "caracteristica" e outra chamada "veiculo_caracteristica" que vai ter as seguintes colunas:

```
id_veiculo;
id_caracteristica;
```

Assim uma característica pode ser de vários veículos e um veiculo pode ter várias características.

Qualquer dúvida é só pesquisar sobre o relacionamento N pra N que você vai entender melhor!

P.S.: Usei veículo como exemplo mas serve pra qualquer um que você queira implementar: apartamento, celular e etc...